# What's the quickest, cleanest way to remove parent pathing from a URL string?

Tags: c#, string, url

In C#, is there any built-in way to "correct" URLs that have parent pathing in them?  So, I want to take this:

```
/foo/bar/../baz.html
```

And turn it into...

```
/foo/baz.html
```

(The "bar" directory being negated by the ".." after it in the path.)

I've tried to hand-roll this, but the logic gets pretty ugly, pretty quickly. Consider something like:

```
/foo1/foo2/../foo3/foo4/foo5/../../bar.html
```

The path I headed down was to move through the URL, segment by segment, and start writing a new URL.  I would only include segment 1 in the new URL, if segment 2 wasn't "..".  But, in the case above, I need to "look ahead" and figure out how many parent paths I have coming.

I tried to use Path.GetFullPath, and it technically got it work, but, man, it's ugly. **Fair warning: you may want to avert your eyes on this one:**

```
Path.GetFullPath(myUrl).Replace(Path.GetFullPath(@"\"), "").Replace(@"\", "/") + "/";
```

GetFullPath returns a file system path from the "C:\" root, so you essentially have to replace that too, than convert the slashes, etc.

I can probably bang this out eventually (and my ugly code above technically works), but it strikes me that I can't be the first one to try this.  Google did not help.

(The answer in another language would be helpful too -- at least it would show the logic.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for all URLs (including URLs with a QueryString):

```
var url = "/foo/bar/../bar.html";
var ubuilder = new UriBuilder();
ubuilder.Path = url;
var newURL = ubuilder.Uri.LocalPath;
```

Comment: +1 It uses the System.Uri class to parse the path so it should be pretty safe for web urls. You can even do it in one ugly line: `string normalized = new UriBuilder() { Path = path }.Uri.LocalPath`.

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek: Yes indeed you can do it as a oneliner. But as you say it is a bit ugly. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) class.  It has some methods that should be able to help here, specifically the [ToAbsolute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150161.aspx) method, which if memory doesn't fail me, should be able to take an application-relative path and convert it to an application absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to roll your own version, try using a stack:

1. split path by path separator `'/'`
2. loop through segments

   1. push any segment that is not `'..'` onto a stack
   2. if the segment is `'..'`, pop the stack
3. join the segments with the path separator `'/'`

But as others have noted: It is probably better to get your library to do this for you.

Comment: The OP actually asks for a framework method. Since he was unable to find one he rolled his own but would prefer a built in method..

Comment: Sure. In fact, that is exactly why I upvoted you. But OP also mentioned he would like to learn the logic. From his post, I got the feeling he didn't grok using stacks for this kind of problem yet - thought he might learn something while we are at it...

Comment: Daren: I do want and appreciate the framework solution, but your algorithm there is really good.  I wish I would have thought of that at 1 a.m. this morning.  I won't upvote because the framework method is "more correct," but nicely done.

Comment: My comment was more a comment on the first sentence in your post. Your solution is good (+1) but from the first sentence I gathered that you thought the OP REALLY wanted to roll his own version. Alas, I was mistaken. :)